# Binary data: How should I make it available if I do not commit them to Git?

Tags: python, git

I am using Python and Git for scientific applications. I often develop software tools that consist of a relatively small codebase and some large binary datasets.

Ideally, I want the software to work "out of the box", without the user having to manually download additional binary files. If I commit the binary data to Git, users can install everything using a single pip command (`pip install git+https://github.com/myuser/myrepo`). However, committing binary files is considered bad practice for a number of good reasons, such as slow download times if users want to upgrade the codebase. Also, a small backwards-compatible change to the binary files may lead to a large increase in the repo size.

Alternatively, I can put the binary data on an external server and let the software download the data if not present on the system (or if a newer version is available). Is there a preferred way to implement this procedure? In particular, is there a standard "download location" where the datasets should be placed?

Answer (score 1):

For big files, you can enable Github's [LFS service](https://git-lfs.github.com/).

> Git Large File Storage (LFS) replaces large files such as audio samples, videos, datasets, and graphics with text pointers inside Git, while storing the file contents on a remote server like GitHub.com or GitHub Enterprise.

I think, if your data will not change very often, you can just put your data in [github release](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/releasing-projects-on-github/managing-releases-in-a-repository) as attachment.

Comment: Interesting option. But this requires the user to install Git LFS as well, right?

Comment: yes. The dataset will need GFS to clone but other files still can be cloned using git

Comment: Hmm... Then I might as well ask the user to download the dataset manually. Perhaps the best option for me is to bundle a "dataset downloader" with the software, which automatically downloads the dataset to a pre-defined location if it does not exist.